# Windows 10 crashes when producing but only in the evening

Tags: ableton, windows, crash

So I've just had another 2 bluescreens of deaths and one freeze trying to work on a project in Ableton live 9.6.1 but this has been happening for quiet some time now (even when I used FL studio 10 to 12 in the old days)

Fist of all the message of these bluescreens seem to be completely random but after googling them they all have to to with driver problems! All my drivers are up to date... The very weird thing is that this problem only occurs if I start producing in the evening (after around 7PM). Even if I start producing before that time and I continue to produce till after 7PM it has never happened to me.

Anyone knows what's going on?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about sound design, but about a computer issue.

Comment: Scan for viruses and then scan for spyware with a separate program. You might have a virus.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to comment, so I'm giving a few suggestions here:

1. Most importantly, my first suggestion is that this be migrated to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) as that is a much more appropriate place for this question.
2. I would suggest *reinstalling* your drivers, in addition to making sure they're up to date. If that doesn't resolve the issue, it may likely be an issue with your hardware not performing as it should - perhaps lack of power or a hardware malfunction.
3. I believe the fact that issues only occur after 7pm may be spurious correlation, unless as @Daniel suggested, you have a virus of some sort. Some viruses source computational power from multiple clients that have been hacked to aid in doing a number of things. The fact that it's always after 7pm may lend to that. If this were the case, there are often other indications.

More information may result in a better answer. What computer do you have? Does your computer start working unexpectedly hard before crashing? How does the program run before the crash? Do any other programs (aside from the two you listed) cause it to crash? Any other weird issues? etc...

Comment: I use a pc I build myself with n AMD fx3580. The pc sometimes freezes for 2 seconds before crashing but not always. other than that the program usually runs fine! i've notice that sony vegas had the same problem when i tried to use my ASIO driver for that... my ASIO driver is up to date though

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the driver? and any other driver that may be involved? It seems as thought the common denominator is that your computer crashes during the use of programs that require a lot of computing power. This could be a hardware issue, which can be difficult to pinpoint. If it is, it could be the RAM, graphics card, processor, or hard drive. Sometimes issues can reside in not enough power getting to components. This can be an issue in your powersupply, motherboard, or perhaps BIOS settings. This of course, can require a lot of time and research to pinpoint.

Comment: Just to note, I once had a similar issue with a PC I built, and it ended up being an issue with the hard drive of all things. There is software out there to help pinpoint issues. Though It may be advantageous to take your computer into a repair shop for quicker resolve.

Comment: The comment rep limitation is frustrating, but it exists to make sure you can provide helpful on-topic information before increasing your verbosity. Thanks for joining and participating, but since you admit in your own post that this question is off-topic, I don't think it's very useful to add questions as an answer.

Comment: I believe it is useful to provide information that will guide the user in the right direction regardless of being "off-topic", which in itself is subjective. The user was left with a closed question, providing no value or direction. My suggestions and questions were added to aid the user in moving in the right direction, ideally within SuperUser. In fact, I do not see how what your advocating adds any value to anything. Your methods would leave the user with no help to move forward. This situation was not ideal, but I didn't want to leave the user with nothing.

Comment: Keep in mind, I absolutely agree there are cases in what you describe is appropriate. However, I don't see this as one of those. This is a source for information and help. I will not argue against your down vote because that is your will, but giving the user nothing does not add value.